# Perl script fails to open port number on modem fails

Tags: perl, telnet

I have a perl script to telnet to particular IP and port number. However, if i print the result after establishing connection, the port number is 23 (default). As a result, at commands triggered from script are not encouraged by modem.

Below is my script. Please advise.

**Script:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use lib ("/u/dclement/lib/perl");
use Net::Telnet ();

$HOSTNAME = "192.168.xx.xx";
$HOSTPORT = "9998";

$conn = new Net::Telnet (Timeout => "1");

$conn->binmode(1);              # don't translate CRLF
$conn->errmode("return");       # enable error trapping
$conn->telnetmode(0);           # turn off telnet mode
$conn->dump_log("LOGFILE");     # output log file filehandle
$conn->output_record_separator("");

print "CONNECTING TO $HOSTNAME and $HOSTPORT\n";
# open connection to host $HOSTNAME and port $HOSTPORT
# and die if there is a problem
unless ($conn->open(Host => $HOSTNAME, Port => $HOSTPORT))
{
    die "Error opening socket:: ".$conn->errmsg();
}
print "CONNECTED TO ".$conn->host().", PORT ".$conn->port()."\n";
```

**OUTPUT**

```
CONNECTING TO 192.168.xx.xx and 9998
CONNECTED TO 192.168.xx.xx, PORT 23
```

Comment: Can you trry manually, or with a browser?  It seems that your are getting dropped to the default (23) -- maybe the port you want is not available for some reason?  It'd be nice to know first whether you can get there in any way.  The code seems fine to me.

Comment: Things I'd try: 1) Set up everything you can right in the constructor;  2) drop any options you don't actually need; 3) try to drop that 'telnetmode' ?

Comment: telnet 192.168.xx.xx 9998 works . it doesn't even expects passwords.

Comment: Note that the `telnet` command drops to raw connection if the telnet protocol is not available on that port. I'm guessing the server running on 9998 is not a telnet server, and that you should use `IO::Socket::INET` instead of `Net::Telnet`.

Comment: I am pretty sure telnet is supported on that port. Telnet IP PortNo works and I can manually enter the AT commands.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below code and see if any connectivity issue 9998 port:

`$telnetOutput =`telnet 192.168.xx.xx 9998`;
print "\n telnet command output1: $telnetOutput \n";
$telnetOutput =`telnet 192.168.xx.xx 23`;
print "\n telnet command output2: $telnetOutput \n";`

Comment: Got errors with the above script. please advise.

Unquoted string "telnet" may clash with future reserved word at fix_sms_cmd_mgr.pl line 9.
Number found where operator expected at fix_sms_cmd_mgr.pl line 9, near "telnet 192.168.xx.xx"
        (Do you need to predeclare telnet?)

Comment: No need to predeclare. you have to put that into backticks it will work. just google for how to use backticks in perl. It helps to run commands on your system using perl script and store the output.